# clipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion

Tags: eclipse

I am facing a small issue and need help on it. I had to re-install windows on my laptop, after that i installed Java extracted eclipse and set the environment variables, namely Path to the java bin directory and also created a JAVA_HOME variable and set it.
Every time i try opening eclipse.exe i get the following error.

The eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion launcher jar.

can some one help me out please and tell me what i am missing here?

My eclipse.ini :

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx1024m
```

Comment: That eclipse.ini is for Eclipse Juno - is that what you installed?

Comment: @greg-449 yes , this is what i installed

Comment: @greg-449 im using eclipse mars

Comment: Sorry which is it Eclipse Juno or Eclipse Mars? If it is Eclipse Mars this is not a valid eclipse.ini

Comment: @greg-449 noted. thanks